# Avoid creating cases (email2Case) if meeting invite sent to routing address

Tags: email2case

When an email reached routing address, a case should be created. Where as if any meeting invite hits the routing address, case should not be created. Do anyone have any idea?

Comment: If Email-to-Case is enabled, I think if you send any mail to Routing Address, a new case will get created.

Comment: Yes you are correct. But my requirement is, the meeting invite Should not be considered and case should not be created for meeting invites.

Comment: This link may be helpful for your scenario. https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewSolution?id=000175832&language=en_US    It basically filters the email address from where cases can be created.

Comment: I Dnt want to filter in respective of emails Dave, I should restrict only the type meeting invite and not the person who's sending..

Answer (score 1):

You can try creating a rule in your email system that will not forward meeting invites in email-to-case service address.

You can only limit email addresses or domains available for On-Demand Email-to-Case.

Answer (score 1):

If you wanna go custom with coding, you can implement inbound email service and do whatever logic you want with the email body, subject and what not. I have used it for plenty of stuffs like email to contact nd email to leads(Web to leads has limits) and many implementations using it.

Here is the link if you wanna go the code way. https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=code_inbound_email.htm&language=en_US

Comment: Yea we could do that.. I already have keywords list mapped in a custom object and it will check when ever an email hits Salesforce routing address. But the issue here is, I couldn't identify the difference between normal email and meeting invite.. I have checked the message internet header also, but no clues...